# Python way of doing git remote add origin

Tags: python, gitpython

Is there a way to this in Python?

```bash
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/xxxx/aaa/bbb/feature2.git
git branch -M main
git push -uf origin main
```

Things I have tried:

1. I tried to do

```py
from git import Repo

repo = Repo("https://gitlab.com/xxxx/aaa/bbb/feature2.git")
repo.git.add(update=True)
repo.index.commit(COMMIT_MESSAGE)
origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
origin.push()
```

but I got a "no such path" error. After reading the docs I think its a local file path.

2. I also tried doing

   ```
    def create_static_site():
        shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination_dir)
        empty_repo = git.Repo.init("tempDir", initial_branch='main')
        origin = empty_repo.create_remote('origin', "https://gitlab.com/xxxx/aaa/bbb/feature2.git")
        assert origin.exists()
        assert origin == empty_repo.remotes.origin == empty_repo.remotes['origin']
        origin.fetch()                  # assure we actually have data. fetch() returns useful information
        # Setup a local tracking branch of a remote branch
        empty_repo.create_head('main', origin.refs.main)  # create local branch "master" from remote "master"
        empty_repo.heads.main.set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.main)  # set local "master" to track remote "master
        empty_repo.heads.main.checkout()  # checkout local "master" to working tree
        # rename remotes
        origin.rename('main')
        # push and pull behaves similarly to `git push|pull`
        origin.pull()
        origin.push()  # attempt push, ignore errors
        origin.push().raise_if_error()  # push and raise error if it fails
        # assert not empty_repo.delete_remote(origin).exists()     # create and delete remotes
   ```

   as per this guide: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes

but got a     return list.**getattribute**(self, attr)
AttributeError: 'IterableList' object has no attribute 'origin/main'

Is there a way to automate the above via Python?

update: Resolved

```
def create_static_site():
    shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination_dir)
    empty_repo = git.Repo.init("tempDir", initial_branch='main')
    origin = empty_repo.create_remote('origin', "https://gitlab.com/xxxx/aaa/bbb/feature2.git")
    assert origin.exists()
    assert origin == empty_repo.remotes.origin == empty_repo.remotes['origin']
    # push and pull behaves similarly to `git push|pull`
    empty_repo.git.add(all=True)
    empty_repo.index.commit("first_commit")
    empty_repo.git.push('--set-upstream', empty_repo.remote().name, 'main')  # attempt push, ignore errors
    # assert not empty_repo.delete_remote(origin).exists()     # create and delete remotes
```

Comment: Where does the `Repo` class come from? Are you using a library? If so, you need to include the library in your question

Comment: Have done so: from git import Repo

Comment: Have you looked [through the manual](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes)?

Comment: Yes i have. UPdated code as attached as above also

Comment: You cannot initialize a `Repo` object from a URL. It needs to refer to a local path.

Comment: Is there a way to just automate this in gitpython with gitlab?

git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/xxxx/aaa/bbb/feature2.git
git branch -M main
git push -uf origin main